# Android Crashlytics fails on direct boot due to disk encryption

Tags: android, firebase, encryption, crashlytics, boot

Android Crashlytics will fail to initialize on direct boot on android. The problem is that the default storage backing a context in Android is encrypted until the user enters their credentials:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#createDeviceProtectedStorageContext()

You'll see a bunch of info in the logs like

> 07-17 16:47:18.083 1897-1982/XXX
>   E/SharedPreferencesImpl: Couldn't create directory for
>   SharedPreferences file
>   /data/user/0/com.xxx.xxx/shared_prefs/com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:settings.xml

Also verified by registering an `initializationCallback` with `Fabric.Builder`

Is there any way to configure crashlytics to use a shared preferences backend by createDeviceProtectedStorageContext storage?

The problem is that if the application starts on boot in this way then crashlytics won't work for the lifetime of the app. This can lead to a lot of missed crash reports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically it fails because libraries like Crashlytics would call `getBaseContext` which invalidates `createDeviceProtectedStorageContext`. For `Crashlytics`, it also expects `getApplicationContext` to return an `Application`. Here's the full workaround.

Implement the following class: (shouldn't be too hard to translate this into Java)

```
@SuppressLint("Registered")
@TargetApi(24)
class DeviceStorageApp(context: Context) : Application() {
    init {
        attachBaseContext(context.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext())
    }

    /**
     * Thou shalt not get the REAL underlying application context which would no
     * longer be operating under device protected storage.
     */
    override fun getApplicationContext(): Context = this
}
```

Disable auto initialization with this in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<meta-data android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
           android:value="false"/>
```

Then in your real `Application.onCreate`, do this: (Android SDK version checks omitted)

```
Fabric.with(DeviceStorageApp(this), Crashlytics())
```

Full sample: https://github.com/Mygod/VPNHotspot/commit/2578c1c6ec67a8b9c7274c6f0e0f47ed030a6813

EDIT: If you want to use Firebase features like remote config, you might need to add these to your AndroidManifest.xml as well. (you might want to add this anyway since this is just a stub service)

```
<service android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService"
         android:directBootAware="true"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, nice workaround. I guess that answer the question, there's no way to do it that isn't a hack :) I'm quite surprised how many libraries fail due to this issue. Guessing not a lot of people have thought about the implications here.

Comment: @AndrewParker I don't think there are a lot of apps out there that even use direct boot. A lack of demand might be the root cause.